# Can fetch be a substitute for AJAX?

Tags: ajax, express, fetch-api

I am wondering if it is possible to do in fetch all the things you can do in traditional ajax?
Because I'm having a problem with a simple login authentication using express. I want to send a response like Login error if the username/password is incorrect, or to redirect the user to the homepage if both is correct, to the client without refreshing the page.

I understand that you can do this in AJAX, but is it possible to do it in fetch also?

I tried using express js and sending a response through a json, but I can't figure out how to handle the response without refreshing the page.

I tried doing it like this in the express server

```
//if valid
res.json({
    isValid: true
})

//if invalid
res.json({
    isValid: false
})
```

And in the client side, specifically in the login page, I have this javascript that handles the submitting of the information

```
fetch('https://localhost:3000/auth', {
    method: 'post',
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
    body: JSON.stringify({
        username,
        password
    })
})
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data => {
     //I understand that in this part, you can handle the response, but the problem is, I don't know how.
    }
})
.catch(console.log)
```

Comment: `fetch` performs an ajax request. ajax is a generic name for a technique of obtaining data from server side asynchronously.

Comment: But yes, fetch is a great update to the ajax mess we had ten years ago, so long as you're on a browser that supports it.

Comment: sorry, I mean if you can do in fetch all the things you can do with the traditional ajax. will update the question.

Comment: @Ardi there is no "traditional ajax", ajax - is a name of a technology, not a particular product/implementation. You probably mean xhr.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are SO close! You've got the fetch, then you've parsed it with `response.json`, so the next thing is the .then(). In that, you have the JSON object being passed into a param you've named `data`. All you need to do is check if that has the `isValid` property!

```js
fetch('https://localhost:3000/auth', {
    method: 'post',
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
    body: JSON.stringify({
        username,
        password
    })
})
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data => {
     if(data.isValid){
       // Do something with a valid user. Redirect or whatever.
     } else {
       // Here, isValid is not set, or is false.
       //  Send them packing!
     }
    }
})
.catch(err => console.error("I died: ", err) );
```

ALSO, take a look at the `.catch()` block -- in the event of an error, that catches an Error thrown by either the `fetch()`, or a `then()`. So you need to add a parameter for the error, and a function body to handle that. I've edited my code sample to demonstrate.

Won't actually run here, but it's formatted all pretty.

Comment: Thanks! Just what I needed. But a final question, can you do in fetch all the things you can do with traditional ajax?

Comment: @Ardi xhr can be synchronous, `fetch` cannot be.

Comment: I use fetch everywhere i might have used $.ajax(), yes.